# Creating EJBContainer with glassfish embedded

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb

I am using a dependency with embedded glassfish in order to create an EJBContainer in the main() method and get the ejb I need for testing. Following the video in my course, it should work, but I get errors related to:

```
5:37:27 AM org.glassfish.web.embed.impl.ScatteredWebArchivist$EmbeddedWebScanner process
WARNING: Cannot load class com/sun/msv/scanner/dtd/EntityDecl.class
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ner.dtd.EntityDecl

5:37:27 AM org.glassfish.web.embed.impl.ScatteredWebArchivist$EmbeddedWebScanner process
WARNING: Cannot load class com/sun/msv/reader/trex/ng/RestrictionChecker$DuplicateAttributesChecker.class

etc.
```

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     try (EJBContainer container = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(props)) {
            MyBean myBean = (MyBean) container.getContext().lookup("java:module/MyBean");
            System.out.println(myBean.getNumber());
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

glassfish dependency that i use:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
     <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
     <version>7.0.11</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This is just a warning from the annotation scanner that it cannot load a class for reading annotations from it. This is a bug in GlassFish, I would raise it as an issue at https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish/issues.

Comment: The reason for the error is that GlassFish Embedded expects class files inside the application to reside in "WEB-INF/classes/". You can see that "ner.dtd.EntityDecl" string is actually the "com/sun/msv/scanner/dtd/EntityDecl.class" string without the initial 16 characters (the lenght of  "WEB-INF/classes/") and without the ending `.class`, with `/` converted to `.`. The call to `EJBContainer.createEJBContainer` probably creates an application archive which contains classes in the root directory and not in "WEB-INF/classes/".